# regex для имён файлов с пробелами

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки

Всем привет.

Есть такие строки:

> ```
> db extraversion.csv db index.html
> ```

Я хочу их сделать в список таким образом:

> ```
> ["db extraversion.csv", "db index.html"]
> ```

то есть количество пробелов не ограничено.

Я попробовал через regex так:

> ```
> r"\\..+\s"
> ```

Но он находит неправильно:

> ```
> .csv db
> ```

Каким regex необходимо пользоваться, чтобы получить имена списком, указанным выше (будет 2 имени файла в любом случае) или может есть ещё какой способ?

Строку не поменять, т.е. пробелы там будут в любом случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
names = "db extraversion.csv db index.html"

name1a, mixture, name2_ext = names.split(".")
name1_ext, name2a = mixture.split(maxsplit=1)

result = [f"{name1a}.{name1_ext}", f"{name2a}.{name2_ext}"]
```

---

*Значение в переменной `result`:*

> ```
> ['db extraversion.csv', 'db index.html']
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*Подробнее:*

Разобьем строку в точках.

```
name1a, mixture, name2_ext = names.split(".")
```

Так как будут 2 имена, будут 2 точки и возникнет список из 3 элементов (которые присвоим переменным):

- **имя 1-го файла**, но без расширения,
- **расширение 1-го файла** вместе с пробелами за ним и с **первой частью имена 2-го файла**,
- **расширение 2-о файла**.

(Я предполагаю, что у вас в каждом имени точно одна точка — иначе (когда бы могло быть и более пробелов, и более точек) как определить границу между ними?)

Давайте, теперь разобьем средний элемент — **но только в первом пробеле** (или в первой группе пробелов), применяя параметр `maxsplit=1`:

```
name1_ext, name2a = mixture.split(maxsplit=1)
```

Получим список из расширения имена 1-го файла и имена 2-го файла (без расширения).

Уже все приготовлено, и мы можем соединить имена и расширения обоих файлов, вставив точку между ними:

- `f"{name1a}.{name1_ext}"`
- `f"{name2a}.{name2_ext}"`

или - менее красиво

- `name1a + "." + name1_ext`
- `name2a + "." + name2_ext`

Comment: Оно. Спасибо.

Просто и гениально

Answer (score 1):

Думаю не совсем правильное решение, но возможно под вашу задачу сможете оптимизировать:

```
import re

str = "db extraversion.csv db index.html"
res = re.findall(r'(.*?\.[A-Za-z]{3,4})(?:\s|$)', str)
print(res)
>>> ['db extraversion.csv', 'db index.html']
```

Регулярное выражение:
`(` - начало захватываемой группы
`.*?` - ноль и более любых символов с ленивым квантификатором
`\.[A-Za-z]{3,4}` - точка после которой идет 3 или 4 символа латинского алфавита
`)` - конец захватываемой группы
`(?:\s|$)` - любой пробельный символ после расширения или конец строки

---

Стоит обратить внимание, так как это больше как пример реализации, в расширении файлов могут быть символы подчеркивания или цифры, это уже зависит от строки, в приведенном примере строки расширение файлов это латиница 3 и 4 символа.

Comment: Тут ограничения по количеству символов, в моём случае их и больше может быть. Поэтому я и без него писал regex. Но я по-прежнему не понимаю почему regex находит не то, что нужно.

Comment: @Breatheoffate ваш регексп выводит не то, что нужно, в зависимости от используемого вам метода получения данных, но вым следует смягчить квантификатор, либо ввести ограничение, если вы хотите выбирать до первого пробела расширение. `\..+?\s` - делаем квантификатор леневым используя `?` или можем исключить пробельные символы `\.\S+\s` что так же выберет до первого пробельного символа.